# query to find doc with at least one of its array element matches certain condition?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Let's say I have documents like this in mongodb:

```
{
  ...
  "cities" : ["san jose", "san francisko", "new york"],
},
{
  ...
  "cities" : ["santa clara", "seattle"],
}
```

How to write a query to find all documents which [cities] array has at least one element starting with given value like "san"? Preferably in c# driver model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB.Driver provides `Regex` method which can accept collections as a first argument, regex expression as a second argument

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Regex(x => x.Cities, "texttttt");
return collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This code seems to work in ver. 2 of c# driver only. Sorry, forgot to say I'm at lower version of c# driver, and cannot upgrade quickly as it's not an easy process. Anything in ver. under 2 which doing similar thing? Thanks

Comment: Well, I found this one works well for me:
`Query<MyDoc>.Matches(r => r.Cities, "$San")`

Comment: Yes, my example is for version 2.x.